# Matrix puzzles from IT site

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, progressive-matrix

The puzzles comes from this site https://www.sweclockers.com/forum/trad/1602971-logik-test. Can anyone give a consistent explanations?

In the first puzzle, my mind is stuck on the last row's middle figure where there are two different bases (white and waves), since they are the same in the top and middle row (grey and dotted respectively).

As for the second puzzle, I have no clue...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could split this up into two separate questions? That way people could answer them separately.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

Regarding the first puzzle,

> The answer must be 2.

This is because

> For each row, there are 3 triangles, each with 3 segments. If you look at each row's segments independently, you can see that it's *black* once, and another pattern twice. It seems as though each row shares the same triangle, but the black segment is moving around and blocking segments one-by-one.

For example,

> In row one, for all of the left segments, we have *black, squiggles, squiggles*. Since the *black* is "blocking" the *squiggle* pattern, we can see that the left segment is *squiggles*.

Following this rule,

> Each row has these segments of the triangles (left, right, bottom)
>  Row 1: *squiggle, white, gray*
>  Row 2: *Squiggle, gray, dots*
>  Row 3: *gray, dots, ?????*

For the last one,

> It's difficult to tell what the bottom segment will be, because this row does not follow the previous rules. However, it doesn't actually matter, because black will be covering it up anyway.

Therefore,

> The final triangle would be *gray, dots, black*. Really, the different bases don't matter in the long run, since it would be covered by the black segment anyway.

Hopefully this can help somebody solve the second puzzle, following similar rules.

Comment: Another way to see the first one is rot13(guvax bs gur funcrf nf 3q bowrpgf (grgenurqebaf) juvpu ner syvccrq nebhaq bar nkvf naq gura nabgure nkvf).

Comment: I came to give the same answer based on @Jafe 's reasonning.

Comment: @Tyler Selden: But then the squiggle pattern and white pattern only occur once in the bottom row, while all other occur two times (except black = three times). How is that logical?

Comment: @Erin The segments in question do break the pattern, but I don't really think it matters, because the black would be covering it anyway. It's possible that there's some correlation between the bottom segment and the other two that I missed, but if my logic is correct, it has no effect on the final answer. Jafe's suggestion might be worth looking into.

Comment: @Tyler Selden and Jafe, all I see when I read Jafe's comment is "rot13(guvax bs gur funcrf nf 3q bowrpgf (grgenurqebaf) juvpu ner syvccrq nebhaq bar nkvf naq gura nabgure nkvf)".

Comment: @Erin You can decipher that at rot13.com. We use it because Stack Exchange provides no mechanism for hiding spoilers in comments.